# Product details tabs messed with other tabs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, tabs

While I loading the product details page is overlapping other tabs check with sample screenshot[image]

Comment: Check is there any error into the console or log?

Comment: Looks like issue with html or styles. If you will provide url to page or at least some part of html code then I guess you have more chance that someone can help you.